# Target [Psr\Http\Message\UriInterface] is not instantiable while building [App\Http\Controllers\PushNotifController, Kreait\Firebase\Database]

Tags: laravel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, laravel-9

I am using Laravel 9 with Firebase as database. It shows that the controller I made is not instantiable while building. I followed the documentation and the channel in youtube, Funda of WEB IT. But still it doesn't work.

The comments suggested to:

- "The path of a URI with an authority must start with a slash "/" or be empty i got this error"
- "if anyone get a "Kreait\Firebase\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: The path of a URI with an authority must start with a slash "/" or be empty in file " just add a "/" before your table name"

Tried these two, but didn't work. Or I misplaced the "/"?
I put the / in "push_notif", like '/push_notif'. But still with the same error.

my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Kreait\Firebase\Database;

class PushNotifController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(Database $database){
        $this->database = $database;
        $this->tablename = 'push_notif';
    }

    public function push(Request $request){

        $postData = [
            'notif_title' => $request->notif_title,
            'notif_desc' => $request->notif_desc,
        ];
        $postRef = $this->database->getReference($this->tablename)->push($postData);
        if ($postRef){
            
            return redirect('notification')->with('status', 'Notification has been pushed.');
        }else{

            return redirect('notification')->with('status', 'Notification pushing failed.');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are referencing
Kreait\Firebase\Database instead of
Kreait\Firebase\Contract\Database

Comment: Am also faced with this issue finally I got a solution. if you can follow the IT WEB tutorial you can use  Kreait\Firebase\Contract\Database; instead of Kreait\Firebase\Database;